# How to use regex in R to 1) extract string between second and third underscore, and then 2) move it to the beginning of the string?

Tags: r, regex, split

I have a column of values that follow this format: "sample_15_gsaco_bin.7", "sample_1_gsa_bin.4", etc. I want to take the value between the second and third underscore, and move it to the beginning of the string.

Input:

```
sample_15_gsaco_bin.7
sample_1_gsa_bin.4
sample_22_abcde_bin.12
```

Expected output:

```
gsaco_sample_15_bin.7
gsa_sample_1_bin.4
abcde_sample_22_bin.12
```

I read through many threads and I think I'm close to finding a solution, but I don't know regex very well and I am confused––I don't fully understand how the code below works. This is what I tried (below), but I can't figure out how to change it so it moves the "gsaco_" instead of moving the "15_".

```
input <- "sample_15_gsaco_bin.7"
sub("^([^^^_]+\\_)([^^_]+_)", "\\2\\1", input)
[1] "15_sample_gsaco_bin.7"
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```r
input <- c("sample_15_gsaco_bin.7","sample_1_gsa_bin.4","sample_22_abcde_bin.12")
sub("^((?:[^_]*_){2})([^_]+_)", "\\2\\1", input)
[1] "gsaco_sample_15_bin.7"  "gsa_sample_1_bin.4"     "abcde_sample_22_bin.12"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6w3TUn/1) and the [R demo](https://ideone.com/iUCU90).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `((?:[^_]*_){2})` - Group 1 (the group value is referenced to with the `\1` backreference inside the replacement pattern): two occurrences of any zero or more chars other than a `_` char followed with a `_` char
- `([^_]+_)` - Group 2 (the group value is referenced to with the `\2` backreference inside the replacement pattern): one or more chars other than a `_` char and a `_` char.